# safest way to take user input, put it on database, and the output it using php

Tags: php, codeigniter, xss, sanitization

this is the most confusing part i encountered today, i'm using codeigniter, but it's xss filter doesn't seem to work properly as we expect, so we tried using htmlentities while saving the data into the database, but i read somewhere, we should never change/edit the user inputed data into database, we should always do that while outputting on the browser, so here i'm totally confused what would be the safest and best way to take user input, save in database and output that data using php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you expect from CI XSS filtering that you think it is not working properly?

To answer your questions, follow all these steps:

1. **Validate user input data first** (and before doing anything with it) instead of filtering and correcting it, do this using CodeIgniter `Form Validation Class`

   Guide Link: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html
2. For your **database queries** use CodeIgniter `Active Record Class`, all data is escaped automatically

   for example `$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);`

   Guide Link: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html
3. **To echo user input data** from database or anywhere else use CodeIgniter `html_escape()` function

You're good to go...

`P.S. Links were for version 2.2, if you're using version 3, routine is the same but simply find the guide on codeigniter.com`

Comment: +1000000 for explaining in steps :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your intention. When someone, without knowledge about your project tells you that you should never modify the user's input, then he or she is bullsh1tt1ng. You need to ask yourself the right questions:

- do I want to protect against xss upon data save, or upon data load?
- how will the UX be affected by user input modifications? Are there some problems? Is there an automatic fix?
- if I am protecting against xss upon display is there a potential to forget any place? If so, is there a way to neutralize this potential security leak?

But most importantly, your question should be:
**Is there any valid potential reason which could validate a user's attempt to inject scripts?**